# Hot to prevent default event when button click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have button click event

```
private void AnswerPressAction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Button validButton = null;
        string buttonName = button.Name;
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int presedAnswer = 0;
        switch (buttonName)
        {
            case "buttonAnswer1":
                presedAnswer = 1;
                break;
            case "buttonAnswer2":
                presedAnswer = 2;
                break;
            case "buttonAnswer3":
                presedAnswer = 3;
                break;
            case "buttonAnswer4":
                presedAnswer = 4;
                break;
        }

        switch (_valid_answer)
        {
            case 1:
                validButton = buttonAnswer1;
                break;
            case 2:
                validButton = buttonAnswer2;
                break;
            case 3:
                validButton = buttonAnswer3;
                break;
            case 4:
                validButton = buttonAnswer4;
                break;
        }



        if (presedAnswer != 0 && presedAnswer == _valid_answer)
        {
            button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            CreateQuestion(1);
        }
        else
        {
            button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            validButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            _gameLevel = 0;
        }
    }
```

and i will change button color in this function, but, button is pressed and i can't change color (button is active/pressed).

how do like javascript `e.preventDefault()`, or run this event before button pressed, when button is not active?

Comment: or plase tell me how to run my method after this event

Comment: Why are you doing the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` calls?

Comment: I want change color, stay 1 second and after change color agan. This like game [Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire%3F_(UK_game_show))

Comment: You're sleeping the UI thread so it can't update the color. You need to let the UI thread finish the method before the color will change.

Comment: Try using this code to set `presedAnswer`: `int presedAnswer = int.Parse(buttonName.Substring("buttonAnswer".Length));`

Comment: Try using this code to set ``: `var buttonAnswers = new[] { buttonAnswer1, buttonAnswer2, buttonAnswer3, buttonAnswer4, }; validButton = buttonAnswers[_valid_answer - 1];`

Comment: Yes, you are right, but hot to run this code in another method? async?

Comment: Peter Torr's answer is the right thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are blocking the thread with the `Sleep` call. If you want to introduce a delay, look into the [`Task.Delay` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx). You will need to learn a little bit about `async` methods (plenty of examples on MSDN or you can search SO).

Most likely you will need to disable your UI while `await`ing the delay, since the delay allows the UI to continue to update (and show the color change you desire) but it also allows the user to interact with the UI (eg, to click the button a second time, or click a different button). The `Enabled` property will help here.

Comment: Thanks, i try using asyc, I think that there is another solution

Comment: @ned - Using `async` is a pretty neat solution here. What other solution are you thinking of using?

Comment: @Enigmativity, i am beginner, i first need to learn how to run async method )))

Comment: If you want an alternate solution, look at `DispatcherTimer` (but it is more complicated).

Comment: @ned - It can be as simple as calling `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));` inside an `async` method.