# Windows Phone manipulate element when method running

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

QuestionNumber.Foreground before tap is red, i try using this code for testing:

```
private void QuestionNumber_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        QuestionNumber.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        QuestionNumber.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }
```

Result: QuestionNumber foreground is yellow after 1 second, but i not see gray color after tap

Comment: You already got an answer for this from your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579921/hot-to-prevent-default-event-when-button-cklick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(...)` on the UI thread, as it will block the whole application (the app won't react to any user input and the UI won't be updated, which is why you don't see the color change).

For testing purposes, you might be able to replace `Thread.Sleep` with `Task.Delay`:

```
private async void QuestionNumber_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    QuestionNumber.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
    QuestionNumber.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
}
```

(Note the keyword `async` in the method signature which is necessary for the call to `Task.Delay` to be awaited.)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, use a Task and code will be executed line displaying results as expected.

Sleep makes the app to tombstone